# When does a std::priority_queue<> sort itself?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, computer-science, priority-queue

I was wondering when the C++ STL `priority_queue` sorts itself. I mean does it `insert` it into a correct place when you `push` the item in, or does it sort itself and give you the item of highest priority when you `peek` or `pop` it out? I'm asking this because my `priority_queue<int>` will contain an index to an array that may have values update, and I want it to update when I do `pq.top();`.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  priority_queue<int> pq;
  pq.push(2);
  pq.push(5); //is the first element 5 now? or will it update again when I top() or pop() it out?
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can discover those properties easily, because like `map` it takes a comparison predicate. If you supply a comparison predicate that prints to the console (for example) at each comparison, you'll witness live when it is invoked (and on which values).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The work is done during `push()` and `pop()`, which call the underlying heap modification functions (`push_heap()` and `pop_heap()`). `top()` takes constant time.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I wanted to hear. I'll mark this as answer once the time limit goes away.

Comment: The example [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/priority_queue.html) demonstrates the behavior really well

Comment: @StanleyCen: Glad I could help, though I really just nicked the information off [some website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/pop/)...

Comment: Oh, I always though priority_queue was a sequential sorted container.  I guess a heap is far faster.

Answer (score 1):

It sorts itself when a new element is inserted or an existing one is removed. [This might help](http://nova.umuc.edu/~jarc/idsv/lesson2.html).

Answer (score 0):

std::priority_queue::push/(and emplace) method causes a efficient reorder in heap.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/emplace/